# VB.Net using C DLL

Tags: c, vb.net, visual-studio, dll

What is the best way to put a DLL written in C into a VB.NET (Express Edition 2010) project? I have the declarations for the external functions locating absolute paths right now like so:

C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\Pelles C Projects\ROBOLIB\ROBOLIB.dll

Because Visual Basic creates so many different directories the program could be running from (Debug, Release, Publish). Is there any way I could tell VB.NET to some files into the program's directory? Or should I somehow customize the installer so it puts the DLLs I need in a specific location?

Comment: Oh gawd... C *and* Vb.net? Oh gawd...

Comment: Now what's wrong with that? I can make good fast programs in C and good user interfaces in Visual Basic. It's better than my kludge that used an API for an outdated piece of hardware from 2000, a C program to send data from it via TCP sockets to a server, a Python server, and a C client software that connected to the server then relayed its data to a Visual Basic interface.

Comment: Oh gawd! No, I'm just messing with you. Sort of. You're still using C, which I can't stand as a C++ developer, since most code I work with is C with classes, and you're mixing it with VB, one of my favorite languages.

Comment: C++ just seems like one of those compromises that doesn't really satisfy anything for me. Too abstracted to have the appeal of C, not abstract enough to have the appeal of VB or Python. Anyway, if we want to continue this we should take it to a chat or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the DLL to your project (either per Drag'n'Drop or right mouse click -> Add -> Existing Element). If you right click the file and choose properties, you can define "Copy to output directory".

Of course, you should ensure that the installer (in case you create one) copies the files.

Comment: Beat me to it!  Just what I was typing, +1.

Comment: Just to add the last detail, the declare/imports statement should then not have any path included.

Comment: Ahhh... Okay... I'm going to try this and as soon as it works, I'll mark this as the correct answer. I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: Ayep, that worked. Not sure where I right click to do this, so I just went up to the menu at the top. Thanks, worked great!